# R optimization with optim

Tags: r, optimization

I have no idea what went wrong in the following code, after suffering for a long time,possibly whole day... i really hope someone can find the problem...Thanks a lot in advance ....I don't know why R is giving me the same initial value

```
lambda<-1 

likelihood<- function(lambda) {
  T6<- exp(lambda*2.82)/(exp(lambda*2.82)+exp(lambda*0.28))
  T5<- exp(lambda*2.69)/(exp(lambda*2.69)+exp(lambda*((T6*0.38)+((1-T6)*2.92))))
  T4<- exp(lambda*2.52)/(exp(lambda*2.52)+exp(lambda*((T5*0.51)+((1-T5)*2.82))))
  T3<- exp(lambda*2.30)/(exp(lambda*2.30)+exp(lambda*((T4*0.68)+((1-T4)*2.69))))
  T2<- exp(lambda*2.00)/(exp(lambda*2.00)+exp(lambda*((T3*0.90)+((1-T3)*2.52))))
  T1<- exp(lambda*1.60)/(exp(lambda*1.60)+exp(lambda*((T2*1.20)+((1-T2)*2.30))))

  l6<-(T6^0)*((1-T6)^281)
  l5<-(T5^0)*((1-T5)^281) 
  l4<-(T4^2)*((1-T4)^(281-2)) 
  l3<-(T3^19)*((1-T3)^(281-19))
  l2<-(T2^93) *((1-T2)^(281-93))
  l1<-(T1^166)*((1-T1)^(281-166)) 

         -(l1*l2*l3*l4*l5*l6)
         }

optim(lambda,likelihood)$par
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code (in terms of a programming error) . If you feel that it shouldn't return the upper limit then you probably made a mistake with the definition of the function in your code.

First of all when you only have one parameter to estimate your method should be `Brent` like this:

```
> optim(lambda,likelihood, method='Brent', lower=1.5, upper=200)$par
[1] 200
```

The reason it always shows the upper limit as the correct one is because your function is only defined between -100 - 300 (approximately) and its value is always zero as you can see below (irrespective of the value of the lambda). When this happens `optim` always shows the upper limit as the right value. You can see your function plotted below:

```
plot(likelihood, from=-100, to=1000, xlab='lambda')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot/......thank you so much for the brent suggestion...ok then I am checking whether I have other errors

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)